# What needs to be installed in a Windows Server 2008 R2 to allow it to run ASPNET MVC 4 apps?

Tags: windows, web-config, webserver, asp.net-mvc-4, redistributable

I've installed the .NET 4.5 framework using the dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe installer, and the ASPNET MVC4 framework using the AspNetMVC4Setup.exe installer in a Windows 2008 R2 server, yet I keep getting the message 'There is no build provider registered for the extension '.cshtml'.' while trying to run my ASPNET MVC4 app.

I've fixed this temporarily by adding a buildProviders section in my Web.config, but I would like to know how to setup a server so that I can use the current framework without having to touch my Web.config (the same way I can run them in my dev machine).

Comment: Was your project originally created as a MVC4, Razor view web app?  When I do that it creates all the necessary web.config entires in a web.config file in my Views folder.

Comment: Yes, it was created as an MVC 4 web app. Besides, it works on my machine (TM), and in two different TeamCity agents that build and test it (using http for the views). The agents run in Windows 2008 R2 too, so I sincerely don't know what else to install...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but "aspnet_regiis -i" maybe?

(make sure to run the version in the correct directory on your server)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx

UPDATE:

Did you also deploy the following .dlls in your BIN folder of your web app?

- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Mvc.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- system.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

Comment: Bummer.  I Updated with another configuration step I often have to go through when deploying MVC apps.

Comment: I marked your answer even tough I still don't know why do I need to bin deploy the assemblies, as they were installed using the ASPNET4Setup exectuable...any idea why I need to do this instead of rely on .NET to know where the assemblies are installed?

Comment: From what little I understand:  These are installed into the GAC not as part of .NET 4 but rather as part of the MVC 3/4 installation which usually only occurs with your Visual Studio IDE installation.  Consequently they don't end up in the GAC on your production environment unless you installed MVC into that environment specifically.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I installed ASPNET MVC4 using the 36Mb setup file that supposedly does that. After the installation there were %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4 and ASP.NET Web Pages folders and all should have worked correctly...it didn't. I'm curious about what I did wrong...

Comment: I also wonder.  I'm sure it's documented somewhere but I haven't had any luck finding out.  My guess is that the installer recognizes Windows Server and by default doesn't register them in the GAC.  Just a guess though.